# Stripe and Salesforce Integration

Tags: rest-api, integration, webservices

i am new to stripe and salesforce integration.How to integrate Stripe to saleasforce and salesforce to Stripe.

Can anyone please suggest me how to integrate two ways.

Answer (score 4):

Check out this links it might help you in integration.

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/04/recurring-billing-with-the-stripe-sdk-for-salesforce.html

https://github.com/cirruspath/stripeforce

Also there is a free app to integrate salesforce and stripe

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000DvMqVUAV