# How to Integrate Stripe to salesforce?

Tags: integration, apexrest

I am a new learner of Stripe. How to Integrate Stripe to salesforce using REST API? and How it works? Could you please give me any ideas..

Comment: @TSmith, can you share any ideas about stripe to salesforce integration

Comment: @Rahul Sharma, If you know pls tell me

Comment: @TSmith, you know these integration process???

Comment: @TSmith  has already posted the link in his comment. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164156/stripe-and-salesforce-integration